# How can i speed up the update on a SQL Script

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-update

I have written a SQL script below and i'm having trouble with the speed it takes to run.  It is fine until the section 'Update Buys with Sales Data'.  It is taking far to long to update the @Results table. Is there any way i can speed this up?

```
USE [IV7]
GO
/*-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    -----------------
Declare all variables
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    ---------------*/
DECLARE @StartDateTime  DATETIME
DECLARE @EndDateTime    DATETIME
DECLARE @l_Section      VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @Debug          CHAR(1)

DECLARE @Worktable  TABLE
(
    PortfolioID     VARCHAR(20)
,   SettlementDate  DATETIME
,   ContractDate    DATETIME
,   BrokerCode      VARCHAR(100)
,   [Broker]        VARCHAR(100)
,   Currency        CHAR(3)
,   TransCode       CHAR(3)
,   TransactionType CHAR(3)
,   Nominal         DECIMAL(22,3)
,   ForwardRate     DECIMAL(22,8)
,   SpotRate        DECIMAl(22,8)
,   DealID          VARCHAR(20)     -- ThinkFolio ID
,   TranID          VARCHAR(20)      
,   TranType        CHAR(3)
,   RKSTranID       VARCHAR(16)     -- This is the RKS transaction number.  It is unique per transaction in RKS, but multi-leg transactions will have same value, allowing us to link them together (e.g. FX's, etc)
,   USDSPOTRate     FLOAT
,   BuyNominalUSD   DECIMAL(22,3)
)

DECLARE @Results    TABLE
(
    PortfolioID     VARCHAR(20)
,   SettlementDate  DATETIME
,   ContractDate    DATETIME
,   BrokerCode      VARCHAR(100)
,   [Broker]        VARCHAR(100)
,   BuyCurrency     CHAR(3)
,   BuyNominal      DECIMAL(22,3)
,   SellCurrency    CHAR(3)
,   SellNominal     DECIMAL(22,3)
,   MarketValue     DECIMAL(22,3)
,   ForwardRate     DECIMAL(22,8)
,   SpotRate        DECIMAL(22,8)
,   DealID          VARCHAR(20)     
,   RKSTranID       VARCHAR(16)         -- Not used for final output
,   BuyNominalUSD   DECIMAL(22,3)       
)

DECLARE @FX TABLE 
(   
    RateDate        DATETIME
,   BaseCCY         CHAR(3)
,   RateCCY         CHAR(3)
,   MDInd           CHAR(1)
,   Rate            FLOAT
,   RateType        VARCHAR(10)     
)
/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Set default values
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
SET @l_Section = 'Setting Default Values'
SET @StartDateTime = '2011-04-01 00:00:00.000'
SET @EndDateTime = '2012-03-31 23:59:59.000'
SET @Debug = 'Y'

IF @Debug = 'Y'
BEGIN
    SELECT @l_Section
    SELECT @StartDateTime AS StartDate, @EndDateTime AS EndDate
END
/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Insert into FX
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/  
INSERT INTO @FX 
SELECT * FROM fn_Generic_FXRates ('2011-04-01','2012-03-31','D','SPOT','USD','999')
/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Insert values into @WorkTable
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
SET @l_Section = 'Insert values into @WorkTable'

BEGIN
INSERT INTO @WorkTable
SELECT 
    t.acct_id                                   AS PortfolioID
,   t.cntrct_pay_tms                            AS SettlementDate
,   t.trd_ex_eff_tms                            AS ContractDate
,   t.trd_brkr_mnem                             AS BrokerCode
,   t.trd_brkr_nme                              AS Broker
,   t.local_curr_cde                            AS Currency
,   t.trn_cl_cde                                AS TransCode
,   t.trn_cde                                   AS TransactionType
,   t.quantity                                  AS Nominal
,   CASE
        WHEN t.trn_cde IN ( 'FFB','FFS') THEN 
        t.fld4_rte  ELSE NULL
    END                                         AS ForwardRate
,   CASE
        WHEN t.trn_cde IN ( 'FSB','FSS') THEN 
        t.fld4_rte  ELSE NULL
    END                                         AS Spot
,   t.exec_trd_id                               AS DealID
,   t.actg_trn_id                               AS TranID
,   t.trn_cde                                   AS TranType
,   t.deal_id                                   AS RKSTranID
,   fx.rate                                     AS USDSPOTRate
,   CASE
        WHEN t.trn_cde IN ('FFB','FSB') THEN t.quantity * fx.rate
        ELSE 0
    END                                         AS BuyNominalUSD

FROM tranevent_dg AS t

INNER JOIN issue_dg AS i
     ON i.instr_id = t.instr_id
    AND i.iss_typ = 'FFX'

INNER JOIN @FX AS fx
            ON fx.RateCCY = t.local_curr_cde
            AND fx.RateDate = t.trd_ex_eff_tms

WHERE t.exec_trd_id IS NULL
  AND t.inq_basis_num = 1
  AND t.trd_ex_eff_tms BETWEEN @StartDateTime AND @EndDateTime

ORDER BY t.deal_id

END

IF @Debug = 'Y'
BEGIN
    SELECT @l_Section
    SELECT * FROM @WorkTable
    ORDER BY RKSTranID 
END
/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Insert Buy values into @Results
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
SET @l_Section = 'Insert Buy values into @Results'

BEGIN
INSERT INTO @Results
SELECT 
    w.PortfolioID       AS PortfolioID
,   CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),w.SettlementDate,112)   AS SettlementDate
,   CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),w.ContractDate,112)     AS ContractDate
,   w.BrokerCode        AS BrokerCode
,   w.Broker            AS Broker
,   w.Currency          AS BuyCurrency
,   w.Nominal           AS BuyNominal
,   NULL                AS SellCurrency
,   NULL                AS SellNominal
,   NULL                AS MarketValue
,   w.ForwardRate       AS ForwardRate
,   w.SpotRate          AS SpotRate
,   w.DealID            AS DealID
,   w.RKSTranID         AS RKSTranID
,   w.BuyNominalUSD     AS BuyNominalUSD

FROM @WorkTable AS w
WHERE w.TranType IN ('FFB','FSB')
ORDER BY w.RKSTranID

END

IF @Debug = 'Y'
BEGIN
    SELECT @l_Section
    SELECT * FROM @Results
    ORDER BY RKSTranID
END

/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Update Buys with sales data
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/  
SET @l_Section = 'Update Buys with sales data'

BEGIN
UPDATE @Results
SET
    SellCurrency = wtSell.Currency
,   SellNominal = wtSell.Nominal

FROM @Results AS r

LEFT OUTER JOIN @WorkTable AS wtSell
 ON wtSell.PortfolioID = r.PortfolioID
AND wtSell.RKSTranID = r.RKSTranID
AND wtSell.TranType IN ('FFS','FSS')

END

IF @Debug = 'Y'
BEGIN
    SELECT @l_Section
    SELECT * FROM @Results
    ORDER BY RKSTranID
END
/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Final Select
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/  
SET @l_Section = 'Final Output Select'

SELECT  
PortfolioID     AS [Portfolio ID]
,   SettlementDate  AS [Settlement Date]
,   ContractDate    AS [Contract Date]
,   BrokerCode      AS [BrokerCode]
,   Broker          AS [Broker]
,   BuyCurrency     AS [Buy Ccy]
,   BuyNominal      AS [Buy Nominal]
,   BuyNominalUSD   AS [Buy Nominal USD]
,   SellCurrency    AS [Sell Ccy]
,   SellNominal     AS [Sell Nominal]
,   MarketValue     AS [Market Value]
,   ForwardRate     AS [Forward Rate]
,   SpotRate        AS [Spot Rate]
,   DealID          As [Deal ID]

 FROM @Results

ORDER BY DealID
```

Comment: Why are you using a left outer join?

Comment: Also: table variables are bad in this case for two reasons: you cannot put any indices on them, and second of all, the SQL Server query optimizer will always assume your table variable holds just one row - and this alone could throw it off substantially. Can you try to make this a `#Results` temp table instead?

Comment: I thought adding the whole code would make it easier for people to understand.

Comment: thinking about it i don't know why i made it left outer, do you think an inner join would make it run quicker?

Comment: Inner Join wouldn't hurt, though it may not help - Its just unneeded.

Comment: Loose the table variables and write it as a query, would be my gut reaction. How many records are you dealing with?

Comment: for the above example i have about 250000 records, for the broker i require it is only 75000 records.  With 75000 records the script takes about 50mins, is there any other way i can optimise my script?  esentially i have two transaction, one will be a buy and one will be a sell and i need to have them on the same line.  The buy and sell match on RDKTranID.  Any ideas better than what i have above?

Comment: I'm interested to know if my suggested answer has helped..

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun - see what happens if you remove the every occurrence of the ORDER BY clause in your INSERT, UPDATE, SELECT statements.

As commented you should really try to loose the table variables and make use of proper (temp) tables with appropriate indexes added.

OR

How about this? I've basically combined all your SQL into one. Obviously I can't test its accuracy but perhaps this will give you some ideas. You know your tables and data better than us perhaps you can remove the unnecessary SQL as appropriate.

```
SELECT 
    w.PortfolioID       AS PortfolioID
    ,   CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),w.SettlementDate,112)   AS SettlementDate
    ,   CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),w.ContractDate,112)     AS ContractDate
    ,   w.BrokerCode        AS BrokerCode
    ,   w.Broker            AS Broker
    ,   w.Currency          AS BuyCurrency
    ,   w.Nominal           AS BuyNominal
    ,   wtSell.Currency     AS SellCurrency -- wtSell 
    ,   wtSell.Nominal      AS SellNominal -- wtSell
    ,   NULL                AS MarketValue
    ,   w.ForwardRate       AS ForwardRate
    ,   w.SpotRate          AS SpotRate
    ,   w.DealID            AS DealID
    ,   w.RKSTranID         AS RKSTranID
    ,   w.BuyNominalUSD     AS BuyNominalUSD
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        t.acct_id                                   AS PortfolioID
        ,   t.cntrct_pay_tms                            AS SettlementDate
        ,   t.trd_ex_eff_tms                            AS ContractDate
        ,   t.trd_brkr_mnem                             AS BrokerCode
        ,   t.trd_brkr_nme                              AS Broker
        ,   t.local_curr_cde                            AS Currency
        ,   t.trn_cl_cde                                AS TransCode
        ,   t.trn_cde                                   AS TransactionType
        ,   t.quantity                                  AS Nominal
        ,   CASE WHEN t.trn_cde IN ('FFB','FFS') THEN t.fld4_rte ELSE NULL END AS ForwardRate
        ,   CASE WHEN t.trn_cde IN ('FSB','FSS') THEN t.fld4_rte ELSE NULL END AS Spot
        ,   t.exec_trd_id                               AS DealID
        ,   t.actg_trn_id                               AS TranID
        ,   t.trn_cde                                   AS TranType
        ,   t.deal_id                                   AS RKSTranID
        ,   fx.rate                                     AS USDSPOTRate
        ,   CASE WHEN t.trn_cde IN ('FFB','FSB') THEN t.quantity * fx.rate ELSE 0 END AS BuyNominalUSD
    FROM 
        tranevent_dg AS t
    INNER JOIN 
        issue_dg AS i ON i.instr_id = t.instr_id AND i.iss_typ = 'FFX'
    INNER JOIN 
        @FX AS fx ON fx.RateCCY = t.local_curr_cde AND fx.RateDate = t.trd_ex_eff_tms
    WHERE 
        t.exec_trd_id IS NULL
    AND 
        t.inq_basis_num = 1
    AND 
        t.trd_ex_eff_tms BETWEEN @StartDateTime AND @EndDateTime
) AS w
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT 
        t.acct_id                                   AS PortfolioID
        ,   t.cntrct_pay_tms                            AS SettlementDate
        ,   t.trd_ex_eff_tms                            AS ContractDate
        ,   t.trd_brkr_mnem                             AS BrokerCode
        ,   t.trd_brkr_nme                              AS Broker
        ,   t.local_curr_cde                            AS Currency
        ,   t.trn_cl_cde                                AS TransCode
        ,   t.trn_cde                                   AS TransactionType
        ,   t.quantity                                  AS Nominal
        ,   CASE WHEN t.trn_cde IN ('FFB','FFS') THEN t.fld4_rte ELSE NULL END AS ForwardRate
        ,   CASE WHEN t.trn_cde IN ('FSB','FSS') THEN t.fld4_rte ELSE NULL END AS Spot
        ,   t.exec_trd_id                               AS DealID
        ,   t.actg_trn_id                               AS TranID
        ,   t.trn_cde                                   AS TranType
        ,   t.deal_id                                   AS RKSTranID
        ,   fx.rate                                     AS USDSPOTRate
        ,   CASE WHEN t.trn_cde IN ('FFB','FSB') THEN t.quantity * fx.rate ELSE 0 END AS BuyNominalUSD
    FROM 
        tranevent_dg AS t
    INNER JOIN 
        issue_dg AS i ON i.instr_id = t.instr_id AND i.iss_typ = 'FFX'
    INNER JOIN 
        @FX AS fx ON fx.RateCCY = t.local_curr_cde AND fx.RateDate = t.trd_ex_eff_tms
    WHERE 
        t.exec_trd_id IS NULL
    AND 
        t.inq_basis_num = 1
    AND 
        t.trd_ex_eff_tms BETWEEN @StartDateTime AND @EndDateTime
) wtSell ON wtSell.PortfolioID = r.PortfolioID AND wtSell.RKSTranID = r.RKSTranID AND wtSell.TranType IN ('FFS','FSS')
WHERE 
    w.TranType IN ('FFB','FSB')
order by 
    w.DealID
```

You could test the accuracy of this by simply comparing the output from your SQL with this combined statement.

Comment: Sorry taking me so long to get back to this.  I tried running this and it takes just as long to run as the script i posted above.